# Story Identification - sci fi novel with nanotech

Tags: story-identification, nanotechnology, cyberpunk

It takes place in a desert city (Mojave, I think) - there is nanotech, a fair amount of dystopia, genetic modification, and I think someone sprouts wings in the end...kind of cyberpunk-ish.

Comment: This is very, very generic. You are almost asking "There were spaceships, I think". Please attempt to come up with more details, they need not be from the story itself... time period written (or read), length, style (young adult, etc).

Answer (score 7):

If you take out the "someone sprouts wings in the end", I would say you are describing *Prey* by [Michael Crichton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Chrichton). Published in 2002, it is described thusly in wikipedia:
*The novel serves as a cautionary tale about developments in science and technology; in this case, nanotechnology, genetic engineering, and artificial intelligence.*